# Responsive Woocommerce category images

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, woocommerce

So in the template file content-product_cat.php for Woocommerce, there is this bit of code which calls for the category thumbnail:

```
<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_before_subcategory_title hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', $category );
?>
```

I'm using Bootstrap, so I need to use the img-responsive class, as at the moment when I view on mobile the images just stay the same size and look terrible.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Every image can be transformed into responsive one, no matter what framework (Bootstrap, Foundation, etc) you use, it is simple CSS rule:

`<img style="width:100%" src="image.jpg"/>`

My recommendation is to use custom styling for your images, all of them or just those with given CSS class:

`img.responsive {width:100%;}`

Place the above code in your theme's `style.css` file. Then assign the `responsive` class when you want the image to be automatically adjusted according window width. You do not have to perform super-duper magic trickery or to use even third party CSS frameworks to achieve that.